# How do you make SQL return duplicates?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

When running an SQL such as the following;

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name IN ('fish', 'frog', 'fish')
```

I get 1 frog, and 1 fish. This is expected and normal behaviour, as the `WHERE` clause no doubt evaluates against each row in the database individually.

However, in my current application I need a full row returned for each item in the `WHERE` clause. The way I'm currently doing it is fetching the full contents of the `IN` statement, then running a second query fetching each of those objects. In python, I am then duplicating the rows as required. But if I could get sql to do it for me, it'll mean 1 less round trip to the database.

Can you force a database to return a response per entry in an `IN`?

---

Example data;

items

```
id | name | price
1  | frog | 4
2  | fish | 3
```

objects for users

```
id | user_id | item_name
1  | 1       | fish
1  | 1       | frog
1  | 1       | fish
```

I'm aware that `item_name` should be a foreign key to `item` instead - but for frustrating legacy reasons, this is not currently possible.

An ideal solution would have me easily be able to accomplish this through the Django ORM - however if that's not sanely possible, other answers are more than welcome.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: I'm not sure if it really helps - but I've added a couple of example tables that express a minimum example of the problem.

Comment: Is 'objects for users' a separate table and you want to show details about animals user owns? What about joining this table with animals table by animal type and displaying only animals table content?

Comment: @EvgenySemionov that's probably the sanest solution - and is very similar to Hooman's answer. I'll likely accept it unless a more django-orm friendly solution arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Fish, Frog and Fish in a temp table/table variable and join them to items, instead of using the IN clause:

```
create table items (id int primary key, item_names varchar(20))
DECLARE @animal table (animal_name varchar(20))
insert into items VALUES (1, 'fish'), (2, 'frog')
insert into @animal VALUES ('fish'), ('frog'), ('fish')

SELECT * FROM items i
inner join @animal a on i.item_names = a.animal_name
```

Comment: +1 I like this idea - but sadly my dba doesn't give me the access to create temporary tables. Do you have any similar suggestions?

Comment: You can generate table like data in runtime. (`select frog union all select bird union all select frog`). But it will work good if number of options (animals) can be predicted.

Comment: how about a table variable?

Comment: If possible, keeping it to just a `SELECT` would be idea.

Comment: don't know of any easy way... IN Clause can be converted to join, they way I have demonstrated above...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it is a very sloppy way to do it without temporary tables, but you could do the following:

```
select i.*
from (  select 'fish' animal union all
        select 'frog' union all
        select 'fish' 
    ) gen
    left join items i on i.item_name = gen.animal
```

Rather than generate a list of strings, generate a "select" + "union all" for each iteration of the animal.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the `IN` clause is dynamically built, you could perhaps try the following:

```
For each animal[i] in list 
   query = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE item_name = '"+animal[i]+"'"
   If i != list.length
       query += "UNION ALL"
End For
```

It's a sloppy way, but it should do the job.